# Geometry type is read as string from the db

Tags: postgresql, geometry, sequelize.js

I have the following model with a a geometry field :

```
const soiSchema = {
    siteId: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        field: 'site_id'
    },
    soiId: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'soi_id'
    },
    geoPoint: {
        type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
        allowNull: false,
        field : 'geopoint'
    }
}
```

I use this model in a raw query with the following options:

```
 await sequelize.query(query,{
        model : Soi,
        raw : true,
        bind : params,
        mapToModel: true
    })
```

My issue: When I query my postgres database I receive the geopoint as a string for exemple `'0101000020E610000000A172ECBF844140CCC38A7B66D93F40'`  and not as a point. The field in the db is indeed of geometry type but sequelize reads it as a string.
Anyone has a workaround ?
I have tried many different sequelize versions but it didnt help solve the issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a proper ST_function for read the geometry data type:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geoPoint) FROM your_table
```

https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html

You can obtain lng, lt as

```
SELECT ST_X(geoPoint), ST_Y(geoPoint), ST_AsText(geoPoint) 
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: this mean that you must  extract lng, lat  .. answer  updated  .